# More C Pointer Troubles

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I have been studying data structures and algorithms, sadly in C. I have separately implemented a doubly linked list which holds integers and works fine, but I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work properly when a node (or pub in this case) holds multiple values of different types. I can create a list and append new nodes, view the nodes (pubs), and then delete(free) them. I have multiple problems with my code and despite my best efforts, cannot solve them. I know I need to free the memory for each attribute where I used malloc, but this crashes my program. I am certain again that my main issue is getting confused with how to use pointers, and pointers to pointers, when passing to functions. Any help would be really appreciated!!

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

# define MAX_TOXICITY 30

typedef struct pub
{
  char *name;
  char *description;
  char *drink1;
  int drink1Strength;
  char *drink2;
  int drink2Strength;
  char *drink3;
  int drink3Strength;
  struct pub * prev ;
  struct pub * next ;
} pub;

typedef struct punter
{
  char playerName[20];
  int toxicity;
  struct pub * location;
} punter;

void append (struct pub** pubs, char name[], char description[], char drinka[], char drinkb[], char drinkc[], int aStrength, int bStrength, int cStrength)
{
  //printf("name: %s\tdescription: %s\n", name, description);
  struct pub *newpub, * iterator = * pubs;

  if (*pubs == NULL)
  {
    *pubs = (struct pub*)malloc(sizeof(struct pub));
    (*pubs)->prev = NULL;
    (*pubs)->next = NULL;

    (*pubs)->name = (char *)malloc((20) * sizeof(char));
    (*pubs)->description = (char *)malloc((100) * sizeof(char));
    (*pubs)->drink1 = (char *)malloc((20) * sizeof(char));
    (*pubs)->drink2 = (char *)malloc((20) * sizeof(char));
    (*pubs)->drink3 = (char *)malloc((20) * sizeof(char));
    (*pubs)->name = name;
    (*pubs)->description = strdup(description);
    (*pubs)->drink1 = strdup(drinka);
    (*pubs)->drink2 = strdup(drinkb);
    (*pubs)->drink3 = strdup(drinkc);
    (*pubs)->drink1Strength = aStrength;
    (*pubs)->drink2Strength = bStrength;
    (*pubs)->drink3Strength = cStrength;

  }
  else
  { 
    while (iterator->next != NULL)
      iterator = iterator->next;
    newpub = (struct pub *)malloc(sizeof(struct pub));
    newpub->next = NULL;
    newpub->prev = iterator;
    newpub->name = (char *)malloc((20) * sizeof(char));
    newpub->description = (char *)malloc((100) * sizeof(char));
    newpub->drink1 = (char *)malloc((20) * sizeof(char));
    newpub->drink2 = (char *)malloc((20) * sizeof(char));
    newpub->drink3 = (char *)malloc((20) * sizeof(char));
    iterator->next = newpub;
    newpub->name = name;
    newpub->description = strdup(description);
    newpub->drink1 = strdup(drinka);
    newpub->drink2 = strdup(drinkb);
    newpub->drink3 = strdup(drinkc);
    newpub->drink1Strength = aStrength;
    newpub->drink2Strength = aStrength;
    newpub->drink3Strength = aStrength;
  }
}

int count (struct pub * pubs)
{
  int count = 0;
  while ( pubs!= NULL)
  {
    pubs = pubs->next;
    count ++;
  }
  return count;
}

void display (struct pub *iterator)
{
  while (iterator != NULL)
  {
    //printf("Display Function Called:\n Name: %s\tDescription: %s\tprevious: %x\tnext: %x\n", 
    printf("Name: %s\tDescription: %s\nMenu: %s | %s | %s\n",
      iterator->name, iterator->description, iterator->drink1, iterator->drink2, iterator->drink3);
    iterator = iterator->next;
  }
}

void clear(struct pub **pubs)
{
  struct pub * iterator = *pubs;
  while(iterator->next != NULL)
  {
    iterator = iterator->next;
    //free(iterator->prev);
  }
  // now we are at the last pub, then clear in reverse
  while(iterator != NULL)
  {
    printf("Attempting to clear pub\n");
    iterator = iterator->prev;
   /* printf("Attempting to clear pub name\n");
    printf("iterator->next->name: %s\n", iterator->next->name);
    free(iterator->next->name);
    printf("Attempting to clear pub description\n");
    free(iterator->next->description);
    free(iterator->next->drink1);
    free(iterator->next->drink2);
    free(iterator->next->drink3);*/
    free(iterator);
    printf("Pub cleared\n");
  }
  free(iterator);
  printf("Pubcrawl Cleared\n");
}


int main ( void )
{
  pub **pubs;

  append(&pubs, "The Queens Cruciate Ligament", "Description Here", "Jungle Juice", "Johnson Ale", "Pubonic Acid", 2, 3, 5);
  append(&pubs, "The Nags Head", "Description Here", "Alco Cola", "McGuigans Real Ale", "Dark Hobo Rum", 5, 2, 3);
  append(&pubs, "The Kings Arm", "Description Here", "Whiskey Juice", "O'Johnson's Ginger Gin", "Bacon Beer", 2, 5, 3);
  append(&pubs, "The The Royal Joke", "Description Here", "Beverage of Truth", "Jackson Ale", "Ginger Ginger", 5, 3, 2);
  append(&pubs, "Flannagans", "Description Here", "Cola Flux", "McGuigans Fake Ale", "Light Hobo Rum", 3, 2, 5);
  append(&pubs, "McFlannagans", "Description Here", "Juicey Juice", "O'Johnson's Ginger Vodka", "Sausage Beer", 2, 5, 3);
  append(&pubs, "The Cow & Chicken", "Description Here", "Giant Juice", "Spencers Beer", "Generic Lager", 5, 2, 3);
  append(&pubs, "Bar Responsible", "Description Here", "Cola Cola", "McMcMcguigans Ale", "Leftover Beer", 0, 5, 5);
  append(&pubs, "The Dirty Donkey", "Description Here", "Tastey Johnson", "Sex on the Beach", "White Russian", 2, 2, 5);
  append(&pubs, "The Butchers Bear", "Description Here", "Water", "Dirty Water", "Dirtier Water", 3, 3, 5);
  display(pubs);



  clear(&pubs);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here,

```
newpub->name = name;
```

you're overwriting your newly allocated `newpub->name` with the `name` pointer.
And `name` is the address of a string literal, which you're not allowed to `free`.

You left out the `strdup` on that one, for some reason.

Also, `strdup` does the allocation for you, so you're leaking all your `malloc`ed memory for the members when you overwrite those pointers.

Use either just `strdup`, or `malloc` (but not with a hardcoded size) followed by `strcpy`.

(And don't cast the result of `malloc`.)